# Query Date from Cloud Firestore and run two separate queries

Tags: flutter, date, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

After 2 days of continuous researching, testing and trying - I'm reaching out for some much needed help!

I am querying a Firestore Collection and return entries that match the query (there will only ever be zero or one result) where the UserId field matches the logged in uid. This works fine. The next step is to check a date entry field, which is a Timestamp in the Collection, on this return and compare it against the date and time as of now.

I need to then go one level further and run a second query, essentially:

- if there is a record match AND the date field is => now, then display x;
- if there is a record match AND the date field is >= now, then display y;
- or else if there is no record match, then display z;

I can't work out what the error message is, and how best to check the date after query to see if it's in the past (and display x) or in the future (and display y)?

The following code produces no error in Android Studio, and the app is able to run, but the error message in the console is:

```
Class 'DateTime' has no instance method 'Timestamp'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DateTime'
Tried calling: compareto(Instance of 'DateTime')
```

The code is:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('collectionDatabase')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser.uid)
      .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
             List<Widget> statusExample = [];
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final cover = snapshot.data.docs;
                  for (var coverIn in cover) {
                    final singleDate = coverIn.data()['endDate'].toDate();
                    final endDate = coverIn.data()['endDate']
                    .toDate()
                    .toString()
                    .substring(0, 10);
                       var dateNow = DateTime.now();
                       final getEndDate = Text('$endDate');
                       final expiredEndDate = Text('No!');
                          if (singleDate.compareto(dateNow) > 0) { // this line of code is incorrect - the corrected version of this line is below....
                             var statusExample = getEndDate;
                             return StatusDateNow;
                          } else {
                             var statusExample = expiredDate;
                             return StatusDateNow;
                          }
                                   
                     }
               }
                       return Column(children: StatusDateNow);
          }),
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to find a solution using flutter.dev - the standard and best practise solution appears to be to use 'isAfter' or 'isBefore' instead of '.compareto'

I changed the following snippet of code to the following, and it works:

```
if (singleDate.isAfter(dateNow) == true)  {
```

Comment: I've managed to find an answer which has worked in this scenario - so I will leave this up, and add an update to the question above - in case anyone else has the same issue

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your contribution. I think that could be a great idea to post your solution as an answer and you mark it as correct in order to this be clearer for other. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have added an answer - but seem to have no option to mark the answer as correct, or the question as complete?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution using flutter.dev - the standard and best practise solution appears to be to use 'isAfter' or 'isBefore' instead of '.compareto'

I changed the following snippet of code to the following, and it works:

```
if (singleDate.isAfter(dateNow) == true)  {
```